# Canon 6D Auto Focus Erratic Behavior

Tags: autofocus, canon-6d

I have a 2 year old Canon 6D which I use primarily for landscape photography and taking shots of my grandkids.  It exhibits a strange behavior at times when I lift it to my eye to compose a shot.

With my finger off the shutter release, and as soon as I can see through my viewfinder, the center AF point, which I have manually selected, will briefly illuminate and seem to lock up the AF system.  When I attempt to compose and refocus the scene with the shutter release, the AF will not respond.  I will have to move the camera onto a nearby object, at which point when I focus it will respond, and then move the camera back to my original composition, where it appears to function normally.  Again, I am no where near the shutter release or the AF ON button, so there is nothing that I am doing to cause the camera to focus.

I have tried to duplicate this condition and have been completely unsuccessful.  It appears to be random.  I have only observed this with my 24-105 L lens, as this is the lens on the camera 95% of the time.  Further, I upgraded the firmware to the latest release just last week, but this phenomenon will still happen seemingly at random.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What focus related settings are selected? What "standby" settings are selected?

Comment: Is it possible you're pressing the DoF preview button?

Comment: I'm not aware I'm hitting any buttons accidentally. Settings are one shot, center after point manually selected, shutter release starts af/ae. Standby after one minute.

Comment: It does seem odd that this happens just as I bring the camera to eye level. Another oddity I forgot to mention is that in moving the camera around when looking thru the viewfinder, if the center point crosses from a bright to a dark area, or vice versa, the center point will briefly flash when the border between the 2 contrasting areas is crossed.

Comment: Is there some obscure setting that needs to be adjusted?

Comment: The lens contacts are most likely dirty.   send the camera and lens in for repair, or talk to a local camera shop about cleaning the electrical contacts on the lens.  I say this because you said it is localized to your 24-105.  ALSO, the 6D has been known to have failing/faulty/issues with circuit boards.   We sent one to repair at work that went nuts on us in video mode and it was expensive. It would record for a second and shut off. Hope that helps and it's just the contacts.